# asp.net OnClientClick not rendered for initially disabled Button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a disabled asp.Button, which I enable later with JavaScript. Like this

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Enabled="false" OnClientClick="; return ValidateFields();" OnClick="btnSave_Clicked" />
```

However, the "onclick" method is not rendered as html when the control is disabled. My work around is to add the following code in PageLoad.

```
btnSave.Attributes["onclick"] = "return ValidateFields();";
```

Is there a more convenient work around for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use the html attribute for disabled

```
<asp:Button disabled="disabled" ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Enabled="false" OnClientClick="; return ValidateFields();" OnClick="btnSave_Clicked" />
```

I assume you then make it enabled in clientside? if so then you can enable it with :

```
document.getElementById('MainContent_btnSave').removeAttribute('disabled'); //or jquery alternative where MainContent_btnSave is the clientid of the control
```

Comment: yes, I do enable the button on the client side by changing the disabled value. Thanks for the suggestion. It works.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's obvious why the framework behaves like this: if a button is disabled, why it should have an `onclick` event handler? The user can't click it if it's disabled! Because of this, the framework removes the attribute.

So, I don't think you have other options besides appending the attribute manually.

Comment: Kind of amusing really....that approach seems to ignore that things happen on the client side too. Ah well!

Comment: MS should have given us better options - like Disabled="" and the Enabled="", cause both are totally different.

Comment: Would be nice if Visual Studio would at least raise a warning in this case. "Your OnClientClick is going to be ignored because you set Enabled='false'".