# If an asp.net button has Enabled="false", it doesn't call a javascript function before executing code-behind

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am working on an asp.net webforms project. On a page, I have an asp.net button which would remain disabled. This button will be enabled after a javascript event. When the button is clicked, first I want to execute a javascript function and then a code-behind function. The problem is that only the code-behind function is called. However, if the button is enabled all the time, which means Enabled="false" attribute is not present in the asp.net button, then it first calls the js function and then goes to the code-behind. Is there any way to make the button disabled when the page loads and then programmatically enable it from js?

```
<asp:button id="btnSave" ClientIdMode="Static" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text="Save"  
onClientClick="javascript:return btnSave_ClientClick();" onclick="btnSave_Click" 
CssClass="buttonStyle"></asp:button>

function btnSave_ClientClick(){
   //js function - do something
}

protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //code behind - do something
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need`javascript:return` on the onClientClick event. see if removing those does anything first.

Comment: You said "This button will be enabled after a javascript event." It sounds like this is already happening, but then you ask if it's possible. Please clarify.

Comment: Enabling the button works fine. Once enabled, it should first call the client-side function, btnSave_ClientClick(). Instead, it goes straight to the server-side, btnSave_Click

Comment: This question has been asked. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990098/asp-net-onclientclick-not-rendered-for-initially-disabled-button

Comment: Hi Skye, it actually resolved my issue! He is using disabled="disabled" instead of Enable="false". Thank you for the link!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to enable the button in the usual html/js way, because the button is already on the page, rendered in html:

```
function enableBtn(){
    document.getElementById("btnSave").disabled = false;
}
```

You could put that one line inside another function, but you won't be able to use it from the btnSave button, because, obviously, it's disabled. Hth.

Comment: This is exactly how I am enabling the button. The issue I am having is that it doesn't execute the client-side btnSave_ClientClick() before calling the server-side, btnSave_Click().

Comment: How do you know? The function doesn't do anything. And you have `return` in the click event which returns nothing. See my comment under your question. Add an alert or something to the js function so you actually know if it's working, OR update the question to show what *is* in the function.